# How to sum one sign only values in a vector

Tags: r

I have avector with positive and negative values and would like to add up separatedly both negative and positive values.

If I do as below I add up the number of elements that have postive sign but not the values of the elements with positive values.

```
sum(x>0)
```

How could I add separatedly the positive and negative values in a vector

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x>0` tells whether the elements are positive or not:

```
> x <- c(-1, -10, 6, 7, -5)
> x>0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE # elements at positions 3 and 4 are positive
```

You can now use `which` to select the indexes of the elements meeting that condition:

```
> which(x>0)
[1] 3 4 # x[3] and x[4] meet the condition
```

And the rest goes from there:

```
> sum(x[which(x>0)])
[1] 13
> sum(x[which(x<0)])
[1] -16
```

R also works with the vector of `FALSE`-`TRUE` to index vectors, so you can simply do this as well:

```
> sum(x[x>0])
[1] 13
> sum(x[x<0])
[1] -16
```

Comment: The `which` part is unnecessary: `sum(x[x>0])` gives the same result as `sum(x[which(x>0)])`

Comment: @Ista ye, just giving the full explanation

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities would be as follows

```
w <- c(2, -2, 1, -4)
tapply(w, sign(w), sum)
# -1  1 
# -6  3 
c(sum(w[w > 0]), sum(w[w < 0]))
# [1]  3 -6
c(sum(w * (w > 0)), sum(w * (w < 0)))
# [1]  3 -6
```